# can I query sqlLocal database

Tags: c#, localdb

I have installed `SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB` with `NO` shared features.

Now I have a C# window service which run with `NT Service` account and on startup of service database is created.

[image]

Now I would like to confirm whether certain table has desired data or not and for that I would like to query the table.

What are the ways to query the database? I also don't have `Management Studio` as well.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have visual studio installed?

Comment: is this SqlServer's service or a custom windows service that you've created?

Comment: it is just sql database, having named pipe interface. First you have to determine instances if there are multiple instances (SqlLocalDB i  to get list). Then get information about pipe name (SqlLocalDB -i "yourinstancename"). And than use this pipe name in sqlcmd -S. Example here in B section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-2017#b-working-with-a-shared-instance-of-localdb

Comment: @vitalygolub, Thanks for info, but for me `Instance pipe name` is empty. Now still do we have any way?

Comment: @user584018, if *running* instance have no named pipe interface - probably no way. Am not sure, never installed localdb wit private instances only